How do I set timeout/retries for pysnmp requests
I am trying to send snmp v1/v2 get requests using lextudio/pysnmp. I have been trying to use the example code:
import asyncio
from pysnmp.hlapi.v1arch.asyncio import *


async def run():
    snmpDispatcher = SnmpDispatcher()

    iterator = await getCmd(
        snmpDispatcher,
        CommunityData("public", mpModel=0),
        await UdpTransportTarget.create(("1.2.3.4", 161),timeout=1,retries=0),
        ("1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0", None),
    )

    errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = iterator

    if errorIndication:
        print(errorIndication)

    elif errorStatus:
        print(
            "{} at {}".format(
                errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
                errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex) - 1][0] or "?",
            )
        )
    else:
        for varBind in varBinds:
            print(" = ".join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]))

    snmpDispatcher.transportDispatcher.closeDispatcher()


asyncio.run(run())


However I didn't see an option to set the timeout/number of retries for a request, so the program would run indefinitely for bad requests.
Does anyone know a good way to do this?

As written in the documentation site, many tips of using this package is there in the unit test cases.
await UdpTransportTarget.create(("1.2.3.4", 161), timeout=1, retries=0)


Searching keywords in the code base can also reveal the same.


I tried adding that, but I still don't seem to get a timeout, any idea why?

I added
await UdpTransportTarget.create(("1.2.3.4", 161),timeout=1,retries=0)
to the example code above, but i still do not get a timeout?
